# Jersey Rest Web Service with POJO Mapping remove fields with null values from JSON String [SOLVED]

Tags: java, json, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, pojo

I have a Jersey Rest Web Service and I would like to send json response removing all fields with null values from json response.
I'm using

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
```

but it doesn't work at both class and attribute level.

My resource class contain this function:

```
@RolesAllowed("ADMIN")
@Path("/test")
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ApiOperation(value = "test Create", response = TestResponse.class)
public Response Create(TestRequest request, @Context ContainerRequestContext context) {
   TestResponse resp = new TestResponse();
   resp.setValueA("Value A");
   return Response.ok().entity(resp).build();
}
```

TestResponse class contain:

```
@ApiModel("TestResponse")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class TestResponse{
   @JsonProperty
   private String valueA;
   @JsonProperty
   private String valueB;
   
   @ApiModelProperty(value = "Value A", example = "value A")
   public String getValueA(){
      return valueA;
   }
   public SetValueA(String valueA){
      this.valueA = valueA;
   }
   @ApiModelProperty(value = "Value B", example = "value B")
   public String getValueB(){
      return valueB;
   }
   public SetValueB(String valueB){
      this.valueB = valueB;
   }
}
```

my JSON response contain:

```
{"valueA":"ValueA","valueB":null}
```

but I would like to send back this JSON:

```
{"valueA":"ValueA"}
```

this is my application class:

```
    @ApplicationPath("/rest")
    public class App extends ResourceConfig {
       public App() {
          packages("it.ivan");
          // Register Auth Filter here
          register(AuthenticationFilter.class);
          register(StartupHandler.class);
          register(MultiPartFeature.class);
          register(new LoggingFeature(Logger.getLogger(LoggingFeature.DEFAULT_LOGGER_NAME),
              Level.INFO, LoggingFeature.Verbosity.PAYLOAD_ANY, 10000));
          BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
          beanConfig.setTitle("Ivan Rest Application");
          beanConfig.setVersion("1.0.0");
          beanConfig.setBasePath("/rest/");
          beanConfig.setResourcePackage("it.ivan");
          beanConfig.setScan(true);
          register(beanConfig);
          register(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiListingResource.class);
          register(io.swagger.jaxrs.listing.SwaggerSerializers.class);      
          register(io.swagger.jaxrs.config.DefaultJaxrsConfig.class);

          Swagger swagger = new Swagger();
          swagger.securityDefinition("basicAuth", new BasicAuthDefinition());
          new SwaggerContextService().updateSwagger(swagger);

       }
    }
```

this is my pom.xml file:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>it.ivan</groupId>
<artifactId>TestRest</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>TestRest</name>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <jersey.version>2.33</jersey.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.29</slf4j.version>
</properties>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
        <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20201115</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**UPDATE... ISSUE SOLVED...**

I removed this dependecy:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
        <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

and I added this one:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Add jersey-media-json-jackson and register the JacksonFeature

Comment: I inserted the suggested dependency and inserted this line  `register(JacksonFeature.class);`
but the behaviour is always the same..

Comment: Do another of your other Jackson annotations work? Also what version of the dependency did you use, the jersey.version?

Comment: I believe that I don't have any other Jackson annotations in my code..

Comment: Yes you do. Try to use `@JsonProperty("VALUE_A")` and see if the JSON changes.

Comment: in ths way I received back this JSON: `{"valueA":"ValueA","VALUE_A":"ValueA","valueB":null}`

Comment: I solved the isse.. the problem was that i had a dependency on com.owlike.jenson package and the @JsonProperty was taken from that package instead of Jackson package. thanks a lot for your help..